# Visual Studio Code Space Errors

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have tried lots of settings based on my google searches and all of my imported files still have errors regarding to the spaces/indentation.

`Please use space for indentation.`

[image]

Every file is full of these crazy errors.

[image]

How in the world do you get rid of this? I've tried to disable `Detect Indentation` settings amongst others but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Consider that it is a single tab instead of 4 spaces.  Looks the same on the screen, why the language service (?) is upset about it is harder to guess.  Googling "vscode untabify" might help to find a solution.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! I will try Googling that tomorrow to see if that helps. When you say, "why the language service (?)" what are you referring to?

Comment: It means I merely guessed that it is the language service that produced this message.  You didn't say much about it and nobody else seems to have this problem.  Good luck with it.

Comment: I see. I have added another image to the post above. It shows the errors I mentioned. This is the only hint it gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Prophet Htmlhint setting. Simply uncheck that and this will fix the issue.

[image]